# Ideas on refactoring controller JAX-RS Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, jax-rs

I have a Java EE based JAX-RS controller servlet that implements a search API. At a high level:

1. It intercepts multiple request params.
2. Based on each request param, it incrementally adds on filters to a search query
3. It fires the search query against a back end search engine and gets back the response.
   The pseudo-code looks something like:

   ```
   //Start assembling JSON based query object 'jsonQueryObject'
   if (param1) {
       jsonQueryObject.put(newJSONObject)
   }
   if (param2 || param3) {
       jsonQueryObject.put(newJSONObject)
           if ( param2 ) {
               jsonQueryObject.put(newJSONObject)
           }
           if ( param3 ) {
               jsonQueryObject.put(newJSONObject)
           }
   If (param4) {
           jsonQueryObject.put(newJSONObject)
   }
   ...
    if (param n){
       jsonQueryObject.put(newJSONObject)
   }
   response = fireSearch(jsonQueryObject)
   return response;`
   ```

... and so on.

Here are some issues that I'm looking to address which is where I need some thoughts:

1. Its a single controller class with big single method - that is getting bigger whenever we support another filter via request param
2. Every time a new filter is added a new request parameter we end up modifying same controller class and in fact same method - lead to forever modified and potentially destabilized code.

I'm looking for thoughts/suggestions/ideas on how to best refactor/break this code up for better maintenance.

Comment: Questions asking for help refactoring working code are off topic on Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: thank you - will do

Answer (score -1):

Consider [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern and how [filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) act in Java EE. I suppose you could implement adding params as a chain of filters and Controller just forward already constructed object to you search engine